# Codeigniter Как получить Переменную из url без названия

Tags: php, url, get, codeigniter

Начал изучать codeigniter. Учитель дал задание передать переменную в url и от этого значения грузить данные.

В routes.php у меня:

```
$route['all_city/(:num)'] = 'main/city/$1';
```

В самом контролере у меня

```
public function city($mass){
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->view('city',$this->data);
    }
```

И я не знаю как получить этот $mass, когда я писал на чистом php, там было название и ее значение, сейчас url ссылка выглядит вот таким образом

```
http://country.kg/all_city/0
```

И да $this->data это тот массив в котором хранятся все данные, а я как заметил больше одного таким способом передать не получиться. Так что я вообще не знаю что делать.
Подскажите как сделать что бы получить уже этот "0" на самой странице all_city
Буду очень признателен за помощь 
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0):

В CodeIgniter шаблон URL формируется следующим образом:

```
http://country.kg/[controller-class]/[controller-method]/[arguments]
```

Соответственно ваша ссылка http://country.kg/all_city/0 благодаря routes.php вызывает контроллер main, метод city, а номер города присваивается переменной $mass. Для ее отображения нужно просто присвоить эту переменную массиву $data.

```
$data["city"] = $mass;
```

Затем на html-странице можно обратиться к этой переменной: $city.